# Firebase returns AUTHENTICATION_DISABLED

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

I have enabled Facebook login in my Ionic app using `$firebaseAuth` but when I try to login with Facebook to the app, it authenticates me and sends the access_token but Firebase returns the following error:

```
{"error" : {
    "code" : "AUTHENTICATION_DISABLED",
    "message" : "The specified authentication provider is not enabled for this Firebase.",
    "details" : "Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the
          new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/"
}}
```

Comment: Seems like the answer is in the error. You can keep using the old SDK with a migrated project but if you use the new SDK you need to go to the new console and enable the providers.

Comment: Facebook, the provider, is already enabled in the Firebase project!

Comment: Could you go to console.firebase.google.com and check the Facebook app id in the auth panel matches exactly the one in your code?

Comment: The app id is the same in the code and the Firebase project. The app secret match what in Facebook. Facebook is enabled on Firebase. And I have added the OAuth redirect URI in the app in Facebook. I spent hours to find what is the missing piece of the puzzle but without any luck!

Comment: Which version of the Firebase JavaScript SDK are you using? And is this a project that you *created* on console.firebase.google.com? Or is it a project you imported from firebase.com?

Comment: I am using Firebase version 2.4.2. I created the project in console.firebase.google.com.

Comment: Projects created on console.firebase.google.com only work with Firebase SDK 3.x or higher.