# getting error at Firebase login activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using this file for create user https://github.com/udacity/ShoppingListPlusPlus/blob/3.27_oyo_restore_signed_in_session/app/src/main/java/com/udacity/firebase/shoppinglistplusplus/ui/login/CreateAccountActivity.java

getting error "The requested authentication provider is disabled for this Firebase application."

even after enabling email&password provider at firebase server.
Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: Educated guess is that you created your project on console.firebase.google.com and are using an SDK with version 2.x. Projects created on console.firebase.google.com only work with Firebase SDK 3.x or higher. See the comments here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501384/firebase-returns-authentication-disabled#comment62502213_37501384

Comment: thanks,,,it worked